# 4 table join with count query

Tags: sql-server

I'm using a SQL Server database with 4 tables like this:

**Product** table: `Product_id` is the primary key of the table:

```
| Product_id | Product_name | Description |
```

**Project** table: `Project_id` is the primary key of the table, `Product_id` is the foreign key to the `Product` table.

```
| Project_id | Project_name | Project_start_date | Product_id |
```

**Participant** table: `Participant_id` is the primary key of the table, `Project_id` is the foreign key to the `Project` table.

```
| Participant_id | Participant_name | Participant_email | Project_ID |
```

**Response** table: `Response_id` is the primary key of the table, `participant_id` is a foreign key to the `Participant` table.

My question is is it possible I can join all 4 tables together and list product name, project name, participant email and get the count of participants for each project and all response for each project?

Edit:
I feel it's better I put my code here. This is what I've tried, so please do not tell me use JOIN only...

This is the code I got total participant:

```
SELECT
    projects.Project_ID,
    count(*) total_Participants,
    projects.Project_Name,
    projects.Product_ID,
    products.Product_Name
FROM
    Project projects
INNER JOIN Participant participant on
    projects.Project_ID = participant.Project_ID
INNER JOIN Products products ON
    products.Product_ID = projects.Product_ID
group by
    projects.Project_ID,
    projects.Project_Name,
    projects.Product_ID,
    products.Product_Name,
    projects.Project_ID
ORDER BY
    projects.Project_ID DESC
```

And this is the code I got total response:

```
SELECT
    projects.Project_ID,
    count(*) total_Participants,
    projects.Project_Name,
    projects.Product_ID,
    products.Product_Name
FROM
    Project projects
INNER JOIN Participant participant on
    projects.Project_ID = participant.Project_ID
INNER JOIN Products products ON
    products.Product_ID = projects.Product_ID
INNER JOIN Response Response ON
    Response.Participant_ID = participant.Participant_ID
group by
    projects.Project_ID,
    projects.Project_Name,
    projects.Product_ID,
    products.Product_Name,
    projects.Project_ID
ORDER BY
    projects.Project_ID DESC
```

Is this a way I can use one query statement to get participant_email, total participants and total response all together?

Comment: Yes. It's called a `JOIN`, which you can use to `JOIN` the tables.

Comment: @Moon, why do you want participant email ? As you are trying to get project level information. I would suggest you to put a sample data and expected result. that will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an example of your expected result, this is the best I could come up with.

Some sample data:

```
declare @product table
(
    product_id int,
    product_name nvarchar(20)
);
insert into @product (product_id, product_name) values
(1, 'Product ABC'),
(2, 'Product DEF'),
(3, 'Product GHI');


declare @project table
(
    project_id int,
    project_name nvarchar(20),
    product_id int
);
insert into @project (project_id, project_name, product_id) values
(1, 'Project 001', 1),
(2, 'Project 002', 1),
(3, 'Project 003', 2),
(4, 'Project 004', 3);


declare @participant table
(
    participant_id int,
    participant_name nvarchar(20),
    participant_email nvarchar(20),
    project_id int
);
insert into @participant (participant_id, participant_name, participant_email, project_id) values
(1, 'Andy', 'andy@host.org', 1),
(2, 'Beatrice', 'beatrice@host.org', 1),
(3, 'Charles', 'charles@host.org', 2),
(4, 'Charles', 'charles@host.org', 4),
(5, 'David', 'david@host.org', 3),
(6, 'Eve', 'eve@host.org', 2);


declare @response table
(
    response_id int,
    response_content nvarchar(100),
    participant_id int
);
insert into @response (response_id, response_content, participant_id) values
(1, 'please', 1),
(2, 'provide', 2),
(3, 'sample', 2),
(4, 'data', 3),
(5, 'next', 5),
(6, 'time', 4),
(7, 'thank', 6),
(8, 'you', 6),
(9, '>.<', 6);
```

Possible solution, using [Common Table Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) (CTE's) to isolate the count subqueries:

```
with cte_part as
(
    select proj.project_id, count(1) as 'participant_count'
    from @project proj
    join @participant part on part.project_id = proj.project_id
    group by proj.project_id
),
cte_resp as
(
    select proj.project_id, count(1) as 'response_count'
    from @project proj
    join @participant part on part.project_id = proj.project_id
    join @response resp on resp.participant_id = part.participant_id
    group by proj.project_id
)
select  prod.product_name,
        proj.project_name,
        part.participant_email,
        cp.participant_count,
        cr.response_count
from @product prod
join @project proj on proj.product_id = prod.product_id
join @participant part on part.project_id = proj.project_id
join cte_part cp on cp.project_id = proj.project_id
join cte_resp cr on cr.project_id = proj.project_id
order by prod.product_name;
```

This gives me:

```
product_name         project_name         participant_email    participant_count response_count
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ----------------- --------------
Product ABC          Project 001          andy@host.org        2                 3
Product ABC          Project 001          beatrice@host.org    2                 3
Product ABC          Project 002          charles@host.org     2                 4
Product ABC          Project 002          eve@host.org         2                 4
Product DEF          Project 003          david@host.org       1                 1
Product GHI          Project 004          charles@host.org     1                 1
```